# Trying to create a function for a 3-component normal mixture distribution

Tags: r, function, normal-distribution, mixture

I am trying to create an R function to generate samples from a 3-component normal mixture distribution with 3 different parameters but I keep getting error messages.

Here is my current code

```
normal.mixture = function(n, mu1, sig1, w1, mu2, sig2, w2, mu3, sig3, w3) {
    p = c(w1, w2, w3)
    x=vector(mode="numeric", length=n)
       for (i in 1:n) {
          j = sample(c(1,2,3), 1, prob=p)
          if (j==1) {
              x[i] rnorm(1, mu1, sig1)
          }
          else if (j==2) {
              x[i] = rnorm(1, mu2, sig2)
          }
          else {
              x[i] = rnorm(1, mu3, sig3)
          }
       }
    x
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is the expected result, and exactly what errors or trouble you have.

Comment: The error says unexpected } however I've checked that all braces are of an equal amount. The result I want to see is a vector which I can plot the distribution of

Comment: Please include the details of the errors you have encontered and the expected result in the body of your quetion.

Answer (score 0):

think you're missing an equals sign

```
  if (j==1) {
          x[i] = rnorm(1, mu1, sig1)
  }
```